# VBA: Runtime error 4198 when using DetectLanguage method

Tags: vba, ms-word, runtime-error

I have a word document that only contains the following sentence:

"Esta es una oración en Español, para un documento en Español."

My intention is to create a Macro that can detect that the language is not English and then execute a given action.

The following code is based on the one found in the Microsoft Page for the DetectLanguage method

```
Sub DetLang()
If Application.Documents.Count >= 1 Then
    MsgBox ActiveDocument.Name
Else
    MsgBox "No documents are open"
End If
With ActiveDocument
 If .LanguageDetected = True Then
 x = MsgBox("This document has already " _
 & "been checked. Do you want to check " _
 & "it again?", vbYesNo)
 If x = vbYes Then
 .LanguageDetected = False
 .DetectLanguage
 End If
 Else
 ActiveDocument.DetectLanguage
 End If
 If .Range.LanguageID = wdEnglishUS Then
 MsgBox "This is a U.S. English document."
 Else
 MsgBox "This is not a U.S. English document."
 End If
End With
End Sub
```

When it gets to a line where the .DetectLanguage is called, the macro crashes and shows error 4198.

Can you tell me what is causing the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a test of ActiveDocument.Range.LanguageID would suffice?

Answer (score 0):

The DetectLanguage method only works if you have added multiple editing languages (whether or not they're all installed or enabled) - and only tests those languages.

Comment: I think you are right. Yesterday I added more languages to my list and word was able to detect the language and the macro stopped crashing.